# Contar registros Mysql

Tags: mysql

Tenho uma tabela onde armazeno vendas realizadas. 
Surgiu a necessidade de ordenar os vendedores pela quantidade de vendas.
Em caso de empate quem fez a venda mais recente fica primeiro.

Consigo trazer com a sql abaixo, o vendedor e hora da venda, porém gostaria de já trazer a soma de vendas de cada vendedor e caso empate já ordenado pela hora da venda.

```
SELECT v.vendedor, v.data_venda , v.hora_venda 
FROM vendas v
ORDER BY v.data_venda desc, v.hora_venda desc
```

Alguma idéia ?

Comment: O valor da venda está nessa mesma tabela?

Comment: O valor da venda é irrelevante, somente a quantidade importa.

Comment: Posta a estrutura da tabela **Vendas**.

Comment: Só fará sentido se tiver mais de uma venda para um vendedor na mesma hora .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você pode utilizar a função [COUNT()](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_count.asp) para obter o total de registros e a função [MAX()](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_max.asp) para obter a maior hora e data da venda.

```
SELECT 
    v.nome,
    (select MAX(vd.data_venda) from vendas vd where vd.nome = v.nome) as data,
    (select MAX(vh.hora_venda) from vendas vh where vh.nome = v.nome) as hora,
    COUNT(v.nome) as qtde_vendas
FROM 
    vendas v
GROUP BY
    v.nome, data, hora
ORDER BY 
    qtde_vendas desc, data desc, hora desc
```

Utilizando os sub selects você irá selecionar a maior data e hora de cada vendedor. 
O `COUNT` irá trazer o total de vendas, pois estamos utilizando o `GROUP BY` por nome.

Acredito que o exemplo não esteja funcional, mas da pra ter uma noção da lógica por onde seguir.

Comment: Certeiro. Aproveitei e aprendi subquerys. Obrigado !

Comment: @Pedro Camara Junior, ajudou bastante, foi uma ótima resposta

Answer (score 0):

Sem olhar a estrutura da sua tabela pensei na consulta abaixo.
Faz um `COUNT(ID)` das Vendas e agrupa usando o `GROUP BY` por vendedor.

Dessa forma você vai ter a quantidade de vendas para cada vendedor.
Nesse caso as Datas não podem ser colocadas na consulta para exibir, visto que podem ser diferentes e isso interfere no `GROUP BY`.

```
SELECT
    COUNT(ID) AS TOTAL_VENDA,
    VENDEDOR
FROM
    VENDAS
GROUP BY
    VENDEDOR
ORDER BY 
    HORA_VENDA, DATA_VENDA 
DESC
```

Comment: `SUM(ID)`? Por que `SUM()`?

Comment: É `COUNT(ID)`. Errei, mano. Errei. Não posso errar ? Vai me julgar ? Só Deus pode me julgar.

Comment: lol suspeitei que era `COUNT()`

Answer (score 0):

Acho que isso resolve, não testei.

```
SELECT v.vendedor, v.data_venda , v.hora_venda, tmp.quantidade 
FROM vendas v,
inner join (select vendedor, count(1) as quantidade
from vendas
group by vendedor) tmp
on tmp.vendedor = v.vendedor
ORDER BY v.data_venda desc, v.hora_venda desc, tmp.quantidade
```